# Generate a RxJS Observable from a sequence of Promises returned from an ORM

Tags: javascript, promise, reactive-programming, observable, rxjs

Am trying to `generate` an `Observable` from a sequence of (batched) records from a SQL database, I am trying to run through all the records in the database. Am using an ORM on node-js, `Sequelize` which returns the records wrapped in a promise.

I have defined a function `fetchbatch()` which fetches the next batch and returns a `Promise[Array[Record]]` and `flatMap`'ing the result to an `Observable`.

My condition(to terminate) is set as a global in the then block of the promise based on whether the query returned no records, but the callback is never called, only promises are returned infinitely and so the termination condition is never satisfied. Any suggestions on how this is handled? Here is a gist of the code.

```
 function getAllPaginated(conditions) {
    var remaining = true;
    var batch_size = 20;
    function condition(){ return remaining; }
    function selector(promisedBatchOfRecords){
      //console.log(promisedBatchOfRecords);
      //return Observable.fromPromise(promisedBatchOfRecords[1]);
      return (promisedBatchOfRecords[1]);
    }
    function fetchBatch(batchNumberAndBatch) { // Returns [NextBatchNumber, Promise[Array[Record]]]
      //console.log(remaining);
      var batch_number = batchNumberAndBatch[0];
      var offset = (batch_number - 1) * batch_size;
      var rs = Records.findAll({where: conditions, offset: offset, limit: batch_size});
      return [batch_number + 1,
              rs.then(function(batch) {
                console.log(batch.length);
                if (!(batch.length > 0)){
                  remaining = false;
                };
                return batch.map(function(r){r.dataValues});
              })];
    }
    return Observable.generate(fetchBatch([1, []]), condition, fetchBatch).flatMap(Ramda.identity/*over the promise*/).flatMap(Ramda.identity/*over the list*/);
  }
var o = getAllPaginated({where: {a: "b"}})
o.subScribeOnNext(console.log)
```

Comment: `return batch.map(function(r){r.dataValues});` this just maps all values to undefined. You're missing a return or just a `r => r.dataValues`. Since Sequelize uses bluebird you can use `Promise.map` which is easier.

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminGruenbaum , just into JS world from Scala, also do you know of any way in which you can ```generate```/```create``` a Observable by executing a function every time ?

Comment: You can just do `new Observable` and pass the source in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that :

```js
const result = new Rx.Subject;
const batch_size = 3;

// Init the recursion
whileFind(0)
  .subscribe();

// Grab the result here
result
  .mergeAll()
  .map(batch => batch.dataValues)
  .subscribe(value => console.log(value));
    
// Recursion function
function whileFind(offset) {
  return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(findAll(offset))
    .concatMap(batch => {
      if (batch.length <= 0) { // Stop condition
        return Rx.Observable.of(null);
      }
      else {
        result.next(batch); // Push the chunk to the result
        return whileFind(offset + batch_size);
      }
  });
}

// Emulate Records.findAll from your BO
function findAll(offset): Promise<Object[]> {
  const data = [
    { dataValues: 1 },
    { dataValues: 2 },
    { dataValues: 3 },
    { dataValues: 4 },
    { dataValues: 5 },
    { dataValues: 6 },
    { dataValues: 7 },
    { dataValues: 8 },
    { dataValues: 9 },
    { dataValues: 10 }
  ];

  return Promise.resolve(data.slice(offset, offset + batch_size));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.0-beta.12/Rx.min.js"></script>
```